# [MySQL][PHP] Have not the same result with sub query : php call VS phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to figure what was the problem, but I turn around and I wasn't able to find someone with the same issue ...

So I have this request :

```
select killer as idPlayer FROM
(SELECT v.idPlayer as victim, v.name as vicName,k.idPlayer as killer, k.name as kilName, count(*) as number
FROM stats_players v
LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_events e ON v.idPlayer = e.idPlayerVictim
LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_players k ON e.idPlayer = k.idPlayer
WHERE e.type="PVP"  
GROUP BY v.idPlayer,k.idPlayer
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS T
group by killer
order by count(*) DESC, sum(number) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**which works fine in PhPMyAdmin, it returns me 1 record, just what I want.**

When I use Php Call (with PDO) with exactly the same request like that :

```
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . SQL_DBASE, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $bdd->query('SET session wait_timeout=120');
    $bdd->query('SET session interactive_timeout=120');

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Error during the connection to the  MYSQL database : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$title['request'] = 'select killer as idPlayer FROM
    (SELECT v.idPlayer as victim, v.name as vicName,k.idPlayer as killer, k.name as kilName, count(*) as number
    FROM stats_players v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_events e ON v.idPlayer = e.idPlayerVictim
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_players k ON e.idPlayer = k.idPlayer
    WHERE e.type="PVP"  
    GROUP BY v.idPlayer,k.idPlayer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS T
    group by killer
    order by count(*) DESC, sum(number) DESC
    LIMIT 1';

$playerList = request_db($bdd,$title['request']);

function request_db($bdd, $request, $txt = '') {
    try {
        if (isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == 'request') {
            echo $request . '<br>';
            // logfile('requete : ' . $request);
        }

        $timeReqStart = microtime(true);
        $result = $bdd->query($request);
        $timeReqEnd = microtime(true);
        $timeReq = $timeReqEnd - $timeReqStart;
        if ($txt != '') {
            echo $txt . '<br>';
        }
        if (preg_match("/^SELECT/", $request)) { /* Return the ID of the last request (INSERT ONLY) */
            $res_tab = $result->fetchAll();
            $result->closeCursor();
            return $res_tab;
        } else if (preg_match("/^INSERT/", $request) || preg_match("/^UPDATE/", $request)) { /* All that not insert return table */
            echo 'Time Process request : ' . number_format($timeReq, 3) . ' sec <br>';
            return $bdd->lastInsertId();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error while contacting the database. Please contact the administrator. <br>';
        logfile($request);
        logfile('request error :' . $e->getMessage());
        if (isset($_GET['debug'])) {
            echo 'request : ' . $request . '<br>';
            die('Error during the request to the MYSQL database : <br>' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**the result returns me nothing at all..**

So I tried to remove the sub query in my request like that :

```
SELECT v.idPlayer as victim, v.name as vicName,k.idPlayer as killer, k.name as kilName, count(*) as number
    FROM stats_players v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_events e ON v.idPlayer = e.idPlayerVictim
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_players k ON e.idPlayer = k.idPlayer
    WHERE e.type="PVP"  
    GROUP BY v.idPlayer,k.idPlayer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

And both action (phpMyAdmin or through PhpCAll) works fine, I have the good result in both case.

Why the php call don't want subquery whereas it works fine on phpmyadmin ? :(
(I'm using WAMP server)

Thank you,

Comment: can you post your php code also?

Comment: Just added the next code line after my pdo calls !

Comment: we don't know what `$request` looks like.

Comment: Ok I've put all my code now :) should be better

Comment: next question is what is $bdd and where is it defined,...

Comment: `LIMIT 1'` is missing closure here. I don't know if that's a typo or not, but I'll have to pass on this one.

Comment: edited. This part is in a require at the beginning of the script.

Comment: In fact the $request is  retrieved from the database, it works fine like I said for a simple request without any sub request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem come from the 'select' at the beginning of my request, in my function "request_db()" my condition waits for a '/^SELECT/', and I send it a 'select'. It's case sensitive so in minus it won't work :)

I change my request from 'select' to 'SELECT', and now it works like a charm.